# Concerns about LaTeX 3 shell escape code

Tags: shellcode, file-access

What are the security risks in this line of LaTeX code, and what can be done to reduce them? The LaTeX3 project wants TeX macros to be able to do file operations via shell escape.

> `{ cp~-RLf~ \exp_not:N \tl_to_str:n {#1} ~ \tl_to_str:n {#2} }`

If you're a friend of TeX and LaTeX you might want to help. I'm sure the LaTeX3 team will welcome your comments.

- Code review on github: https://github.com/latex3/latex3/commit/7b62e64dde239f9cb6ae0f08400c0b5ccde815d8#diff-09def3f98d60fce78fbcc00e77c65795R3093
- LaTeX 3 issue: [State clearly security aspects of l3sys-shell #472](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/472)

Other relevant URLs.

- Initial request: https://github.com/tohecz/yoin/issues/3
- LaTeX 3 issue:
  https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/468
- Post to LaTeX3 mailinglist:
  https://listserv.uni-heidelberg.de/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind1808&L=LATEX-L&F=&S=&P=73

Comment: This has been discussed on github, in [**code review**](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/commit/7b62e64dde239f9cb6ae0f08400c0b5ccde815d8#diff-09def3f98d60fce78fbcc00e77c65795R3093) of the changed file.

I've also raised an issue **[State clearly security aspects of l3sys-shell #472](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/472)** .